# Change event of dropdown list does not fire

Tags: jquery

I have two lists. Selecting an item in first list fires an ajax event to populate the list items for  the second list.
Once the second list is populated, it does not fire the change event on selecting an item.
Here's the relevant code for both  the lists:

```
<h:selectOneMenu class="RUIFW-from-el" id="fromList" value="#{uiBean.value}" >
                        <f:selectItems value="#{uiBean.fromAcctList}" />
                        <f:ajax listener="#{uiBean.fromAcctChangeListener}" render="toList" onevent="function(data) { if (data.status==='success') {reRenderCSS('content_block'); }}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
<h:selectOneMenu class="RUIFW-from-el" id="toList" value="#{uiBean.tovalue}" 
                                >
<f:selectItems value="#{uiBean.toAcctList}" /> 
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

jQuery Code for Change event

```js
$("#contentForm\\:toList").change(function () {
    alert('toList');
});
```

Comment: have you put the script inside document.ready or inialized it in any way?

Comment: Call me dense, but I have no idea why `$("#contentForm\\:toList")` would even work. I've never seen a jQuery selector like that. Since your second list has an `id` of `"toList"` wouldn't your selector simply be `$("#toList").change(function(){ });`?

Comment: yes,  the script is initialized and when i hard code the items in the second list, the change event does fires. The issue seems to be around the refresh of second list after the ajax call in the change event of first list.